# Solr with mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, solr

Connect my mongodb database with solr cloud using mongo-connector?
can any one tell me the steps to connect the mongo database to fetch data to the solr for indexing

Comment: what did you try so far? did you read mongo-connector documentation?

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr
https://github.com/hrishik/solr-mongodb-dih
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongo-connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1**: Installing the Mongo Connector

To install the mongo connector run

```
 Pip install mongo-connector
```

**Step 2**: Creating a Solr Core

```
 ./bin/solr create -c <corename>-p 8983 -s 3 -rf 3
```

**Step 3**:Configuring to Solr

The fields in the mongodb documents to be indexed are specified in the schema.xml configuration file . open the schema.xml in a vi editor. As

```
vi/solr/solr-6.6.2/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/ 
conf/schema.xml
```

**Step 4**: Mongo Connector also stores the metadata associated with the each mongodb document it indexes in fields ns and _ts. Also add the ns and _ts fields to the schema.xml.

```
<schema>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
<field name="time_stamp" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="category" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="servername" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="code" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="msg" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  
multiValued="false" />
<field name="_ts" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="ns" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

</schema>
```

**Step 5**:We also need to configure the
 org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler request handler in the solrconfig.xml.

Open the solrconfig.xml in the vi editor.

```
 vi ./solr-5.3.1/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

Specify the request handler for the Mongo Connector.

```
*<requestHandler name="/admin/luke" 
class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />*
```

Also configure the auto commit to true so that Solr auto commits the data from MongoDB after the configured time.

```
<autoCommit>
<maxTime>15000</maxTime>
<openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```

**Step 6**:Solr needs to be restarted

```
Bin/solr restart -force
```

**Starting MongoDB Server**
Mongo Connector requires a MongoDB replica set to be running for it to index MongoDB data in Solr. A replica set is a cluster of MongoDB servers that implements replication and automatic failover. A replica set could consist of only a single server and  the port is specified as 27017, the data directory for MongoDB is specified as /data/db and the replica set name is specified as rs0 with the –replSet option.

```
Sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --replSet rs0
```

**Step 7**: Starting MongoDB Shell
Start the Mongodb shell with the following command

```
Mongo
```

MongoDB shell gets started. We need to initiate the replica set. Run the following command to initiate the replica set.

```
 rs.initiate()
```

**Step 8**:Starting MongoDB Connector and Indexing MongoDB Database with Solr
Run Mongo-connector command as below

```
mongo-connector --unique-key=id –n solr.wlslog -m localhost:27017 -t 
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8983/solr/wlslog -d solr_doc_manager
```

In above statement
solr.wlslog--> solr is a databasename wlslog is a collection name
Solr/wlslog--> wlslog is a CORE name

For Future reference use the below link
https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/nosql/b/weblog/archive/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr

Comment: for solr-5.3.1 and MongoDB 3.4
The answer shows research efforts .